# How PHP variable variables work?

Tags: php, variables

I know how PHP variable variables works, but have trouble understanding
why this script outputs "I am r." instead of "I am B."

```
<?php
class fooo {
    var $bar = 'I am bar.';
    var $arr = array('I am A.', 'I am B.', 'I am C.');
    var $r   = 'I am r.';
}
$fooo = new fooo();
$arr = 'arr';
echo $fooo->$arr[1] . "\n";
//above line output
//I am r.
?>
```

Comment: `$arr` inside the class belongs to the class (a property of it). When you set the `$arr` inside `fooo()` you do: `$fooo->arr = 'arr';`. The `$arr` you set now belongs to the normal scope and not the one inside the instanced object of the class `fooo`. Try to Google a bit on how scopes work in programming. It will become much more clearer :)

Comment: $arr inside the foo class is encapsulated and points different memory address from $arr variable points

Comment: @SamDufel and that helps him how? We don't all have the same level of skill or the same pace of learning. We should embrace people who are new to coding just as much as people with a lot experience and adjust our response to their skillset.

Comment: Apparently `$fooo->$arr[1]` is equivalent to `$fooo->{$arr[1]}`

Comment: @Allendar - my point was that it's an extremely obscure way to access a property.  Constructs like that are OK if you're trying to test someone's knowledge a language, but it's also something you would never need to use.  Furthermore, I wrote it as a comment, not an answer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are defining `$arr = 'arr';` and then getting the second character from the string 'arr', not the array inside class Foo, that is why you are getting 'r' (`[1]` returning the second character from your word).

**The solution?** you should replace:

```
echo $fooo->$arr[1] . "\n";
```

with:

```
echo $fooo->arr[1] . "\n";
```

You should receive your desired output:

```
'I am B.'
```

Answer (score 0):

When you reference an object property, it's the name of the variable, not the variable itself. So you'll want to do:

```
echo $fooo->arr[1] . "\n";
```

To get what you expected.

Answer (score 0):

To get the 'I am B'.

You need to resolve **$arr** first.

```
echo $fooo->${$arr}[1]
```

The reason being is the scope of the variable which is **$arr='arr'** not the property
**$arr=array**